# Perl5 compile-time err "I don't know where I am! (Do you?)"

Tags: perl

I haven't found this compile-time error in Perl documentation or Web searches; does it ring a bell for anybody? Perl 5.32 on Windows.
The full error:

```
I don't know where I am! (Do you?) DESKTOP-FUM 
Compilation failed in require at distrib.bat line 23. 
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at distrib.bat line 23.
```

The code in distrib.bat begins:

```
use 5.010; use strict 'subs'; use integer; use warnings; use English;
use File::Copy; use Getopt::Std; use Time::Piece; use feature 'switch';
BEGIN { # determine where to find my library
unshift @INC, ($^0 eq "darwin") ? "/Users/roddy/foopath" : "$ENV{USERPROFILE}/fumpath";
} # BEGIN
use rwelib;  # <- line 23
```

rwelib has no BEGIN block; it starts with the only "require" in the code:

```
require 5; use English;
use Sys::Hostname;
(etc)
```

distrib.bat uses a typical wrapper for Perl scripts. Line number was adjusted accordingly.

I've run this script many times; this error happens on a new Perl installation in India, so it's slow for me to debug!

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you edit `rwelib`? if yes add `BEGIN` statements to narrow down what/where fails?  Clearly there is a problem with that `FUM` thing at that `fumpath` but I have no idea what that is...

Comment: Don't need a `BEGIN` block to get that `BEGIN failed--compilation aborted...` (run with `use NoLib;` to see...).  So what other `use` statements are there in `rwelib`?

Comment: The error isn't from Perl itself. Searching for the phrase turns up absolutely no matches (except this page). You'll need to continue debugging to find the source.

Comment: trace file access with [procmon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) then examine those files?

Comment: `use` is basically a `require` (and `import`) inside a `BEGIN`. Both the `require` and the `BEGIN` in the error messages refer to `use rwelib;`.

Comment: Other uses in rwelib, after the Sys::Hostname are use if $OSNAME eq "MSWin32", "Win32"; use Encode; use Text::CSV; use File::BOM qw(open_bom);

Comment: No idea what you're saying that. As I already said, both the `require` and the `BEGIN` in the error messages refer to `use rwelib;`. So that's all the info you get from the error message. As I already said, you will need to continue debugging.

Comment: @ikegami "_No idea what you're saying that_"  -- I asked, in the second comment.  The error seems to come from a  `use` statement in `rwelib` so I asked what is getting loaded in that lib.  @Mugwort -- none of those seem to be the culprit.  Again, can you edit `rwelib`?  Pepper it with `BEGIN` statements to bracket the place where the error happens.

Comment: @Mugwort  (If you can't edit `rwelib` -- and you think that that seems to be the problem -- then copy it locally, make the program load _that_ one, and then you can edit/debug as you wish.  That should work as the lib doesn't seem to load any custom libraries, as you say)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, all, for your thoughtful responses, which I've noted for the future.
I had neglected the basic principle that error messages should be clear and indicate where they originate. And forgotten that below the many functions defined in the library file, initialization code had been written a few years ago. It didn't recognize the new host, and was being cute. (sigh) I should know better; off my game for some reason.

Comment: Alright, thanks for posting the resolution.  It's OK to "accept" your own answer as well so that the matter is settled.  (Another option would be to delete the question since it's non-repeatable by other people.)

Comment: `perl -MCarp::Always prog.pl` Sorry, just came to mind. Of course, just grepping your code base would have found it too.

Comment: zdim: Sadly, I can't delete the question because of the responses. I'll be able to accept my own answer in 15h